# How to generate 3 node treeview in winforms with mysql?

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

[image: Database]

I am implementing a  database so I have coded like...

```
   string MyConString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["College_Management_System.Properties.Settings.cmsConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConString);
            MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
            MySqlDataReader Reader;
            command.CommandText = "select * from menu_right";
            connection.Open();
            Reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (Reader.Read())
            {
                if (Reader[2].ToString() == Convert.ToString(0))
                {
                    treeView1.Nodes.Add(Reader[3].ToString(), Reader[1].ToString());
                }

                if (Reader[2].ToString() == Convert.ToString(1))
                {
                    treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add(Reader[3].ToString(), Reader[1].ToString());
                }

                if (Reader[2].ToString() == Convert.ToString(4))
                {
                    treeView1.Nodes[1].Nodes.Add(Reader[3].ToString(), Reader[1].ToString());
                }

                if (Reader[2].ToString() == Convert.ToString(18))
                {
                    treeView1.Nodes[1].Nodes[0].Nodes.Add(Reader[3].ToString(), Reader[1].ToString());
                }
            }
            connection.Close();
```

but it throw an error,

> Specified argument was out of the
>   range of valid values. Parameter name:
>   index

at,

```
treeView1.Nodes[1].Nodes[0].Nodes.Add(Reader[3].ToString(), Reader[1].ToString());
```

what is the problem in my code.?.

Is any other way to simplify code for my requirement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error comes from the fact that the records with parent_id == 18 get read before the record with parent_id == 4. Your `treeView1.Nodes[1].Node[0]` has not yet been added at the time you call it.

You could possibly avoid this situation with something like 'order by parent_id' to ensure that the records will come back in the order you're expecting them, however this code will still be difficult to maintain as it is already difficult to read/understand.